# c# how get the message (json) from a 404 error page

Tags: c#, json, http-status-code-404

I have an API that is returning #404 with a json message like
{"statusCode":404,"message":" id=12345 was not found"}

I need to be able to read that message, I tried different combinations like this

```
       string json = null;
        var wc = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            json = wc.DownloadString(url);
        }

        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the StatusCode "Not Found" but the "errorText" is always "" (blank) and Length=0

Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you try to use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to see how the server answer looks like, before trying to parse it? Maybe this clears it up a bit.

Comment: you want to deserialize the ``json`` string or get the status code and errorText inside exception?

Comment: Yes, the first thing I did was trying with postman and it return the json                    {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "case id=317040 was not found"
}

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get when testing with postman { "statusCode": 404, "message": "id=612345 was not found" }

This is a screen capture from postman

[Postman screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu2zx.png)